# Javascript mouse over

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the mouse over function working in my pure Javascript (no jQuery, HTML or CSS). At the moment I have created just a small circle and when I mouse over it I want it to change colors.

[image: myCode]

`instance.threadContext` is just the part of the canvas where the circle is being drawn.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please post the code here, all of it so we can help

Comment: I wish I could post more of it but this is the limit of what I can post.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that when you draw something onto a canvas, it does not become a ui element, but is actually a part of the overall image of the canvas. The reason you can't invoke a mouse-over event on the circle is because the circle isn't a thing that can receive events, it's just a drawing of a circle on an element which itself **can** receive events.

One way that you can get around this is to measure the mouse position on move and redraw the circle in an over state when the position is within the area for which you want the event to be triggered.

Comment: thank you very much this ended up helping me focus and find a new way to fix my problem